# Change start of a CSS3 animation

Tags: javascript, css, css-animations

I wanted to create a table with color-changing rows (for example: from complete green background to complete red in half an hour starting from 12o'clock). I managed to do this but now i thought about a case where the site is being called when the time's row is already 10 min up (so not half an hour of gradient progress but only 20 minutes and the row wouldn't start completely green).

so i wondered if it is possible to set the start time of a CSS animation.
Maybe over a keyframe? i have literally no idea cause i didn't work much with css3 the past time and i would be thankful for any information :)

[my animation css]

```
.timing {
background: linear-gradient(88deg, #05a400, #ff0000);
background-size: 400% 400%;

-webkit-animation: Gradient 180s linear infinite;
-moz-animation: Gradient 180s linear infinite;
animation: Gradient 180s linear infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes Gradient {
0%{background-position:0% 53%}
50%{background-position:100% 48%}
100%{background-position:0% 53%}
}
@-moz-keyframes Gradient {
0%{background-position:0% 53%}
50%{background-position:100% 48%}
100%{background-position:0% 53%}
}
@keyframes Gradient { 
0%{background-position:0% 53%}
50%{background-position:100% 48%}
100%{background-position:0% 53%}
}
```

and sorry if the header isn't clearly stating my question, i didn't find the proper words...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use CSS variable to adjust the starting time of an animation then you can simply modify it using JS:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.timing')[1].style.setProperty('--t','5s');
```

```css
.timing {
  background: linear-gradient(88deg, #05a400, #ff0000);
  background-size: 400% 400%;
  animation: Gradient 2s linear infinite var(--t,0s);
  height:80px;
  color:#fff;
  font-size:30px;
}

@keyframes Gradient {
  0% {
    background-position: 0% 53%
  }
  50% {
    background-position: 100% 48%
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 0% 53%
  }
}
```

```html
<div  class="timing">
This one will start immediately
</div>
<div  class="timing">
This one will start after 5s
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, this solution is perfect! And i didn't know the browser specific selectors aren't necessary anymore. Thanks alot! :)